# What assumptions do I have to make about monitors (in OS)?

Tags: operating-systems

I am taking a course in Operating Systems. I am going through old exams and there is a question about monitors. We are supposed to give a solution for the producer-consumer problem using monitors. That is quite clear. But, it also says in the question:

*List also the assumptions that you make about monitor semantics*

Can anyone explain what is meant by this?

Comment: Consider what the monitor pattern is, and that producer and consumer are asynchronous processes. Shared data structures require synchronization to ensure that each views the shared data in a consistent state and leaves it in a consistent after it makes any changes.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little bit? isn't what you are saying the very essence of monitors? to my understanding, that's exactly what a monitor does - only allows one process at a time in the critical section.

Comment: How about asking your instructor?

Comment: perhaps i asked and didn't get a response. or i got a response that didn't cleared it up for me. or I don't want to ask him for one reason or another. there can be many reasons. it is totally irrelevant to the question. if you feel this is not a good question, downvote it or vote to close it. i never understand why people bother writing unfriendly and useless comments like yours.

Comment: One way to interpret the comment might be: we encourage people to do research to try to figure out the answer on their own before asking, and show us in the question what research they've done.  How much research?  [A lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723).  What kind of research could you do?  One thing you could do is ask your instructor.  (Rather than telling us what perhaps you might have done, I suggest you tell us what you actually did do.)  Another thing is you could check standard textbooks and Wikipedia to see if there are multiple kinds of monitors.

Comment: Showing us what research you've done and where you've looked, and what you've found so far, helps us give you better answers, and makes your question more interesting and useful for others.  So, I encourage you to exhaust all available avenues for  researching this, and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Finally, if you want us to interpret what the author of that exam meant, your best bet might be to ask the author (or your instructor) -- they will have all the context and know what they had in mind.  We can answer technical questions, but it's possible that interpreting what the author meant by that statement might be more of a matter of opinion or guesswork.  I share this in the spirit of trying to help you have the best chance of finding a useful answer here.